# How to differentiate between repo and built packages with dnf?

Tags: fedora, package-management, rpm, dnf

When I build an `rpm` package with the same name as a package that already exists in a repo and type the command

```
$ dnf info package
```

This command only shows information about the built package. I would like to be able to run above command and `dnf builddep package`, and be able to choose which package I get information from.

Is there a way to differentiate between repo and self built packages without giving them different names?

**Addendum:** *Built packages have newer versions*

Answer (score 2):

Look at the lines `Repo` and `From repo` in the `dnf info` output. These will tell you:

- `Repo` tells you the repository that an available package is in. If the package is *installed* then it will tell you `@System`.
- `From repo` appears only for installed packages. It gives the repository from which an installed package originated. It shows a repo name (e.g. `fedora` or `updates`) or `@commandline` for a manually installed RPM.

`dnf builddep` will install build dependencies for the latest version of the named package in the repositories. It doesn't do anything with manually installed RPMs.

Comment: Ahh I see now, but how would I differentiate packages when using `dnf builddep package`? If I have two packages with the same name, will it not just return results for one of them only?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia If you've got two packages with the same name, they should be the same software (even if different versions).

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia And in any case, if you're rebuilding source RPMs and _not_ using `mock` then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I don't get `@commandline` for a package I installed using `rpm -ivh`. However, the rest is correct. I am using `fpm`, what can `mock` do that makes it necessary when building source RPM's?

Comment: If you're installing deps in order to build a package, the _spec file_ should be the source of the deps anyway. `dnf builddep package.spec` — problem solved, no ambiguity. (Otherwise, it'll select a package to pull the deps from the same way it selects a package to install. You can have two packages with the same name in two different repos, as well. Of course, if two packages have the same name _and_ version identifiers, why wouldn't they have the same build deps?

Comment: As for what Mock gets you: It builds the package in a clean, sandboxed environment, unpolluted by your source system. One of the problems with building RPMs from source/spec is that all of the packages installed on your system are available to the build. Which means that a dependency might be pulled in, even though it's _not_ listed in the package's BuildDeps. This can create hidden or unintended dependencies. Mock protects against that, by ensuring that **only** the explicitly declared BuildDeps are installed in the build sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `dnf builddep` to install the deps of a *specific* package, simply be more specific. In other words, you can do all of the following:

```bsh
$ sudo dnf builddep somepackage-1.2.3
$ sudo dnf builddep somepackage-1.2.3-9.fc30
$ sudo dnf builddep /path/to/some/uninstalled/somepackage-1.2.4-1.fc30.$arch.rpm
$ sudo dnf builddep /path/to/some/unbuilt/somepackage-1.2.4-2.fc30.srpm
$ sudo dnf builddep /path/to/some/unbuilt/somepackage.spec
```

Ditto with `dnf info`, for the first two. (You can't run `dnf info` on a file path to an RPM, SRPM, or spec, somewhat surprisingly. You **can** do `rpm -q -i -p /path/to/uninstalled.{rpm,srpm}` — just have to remember to include the `-p` flag — but there's nothing similar with `dnf info`.)

The only time you can't be completely specific about a package's source is when there are packages in two different repos, which have literally the ***exact** same* NVR.

Like, say I `dnf download --source`'d an SRPM for a package in the Fedora `updates` repo, built local RPMs with `rpmbuild -rb`, then added them to the local repo I maintain for my own packages. By default, that'll be `somepackage-1.2.5-1.fc30.x86_64.rpm` or whatever, exactly the same as the one in the `updates` repo.

Because of that ambiguity, my `$HOME/.rpmmacros` contains the following:

```
%dist           .ferd%{fedora}
```

That ensures the version I build locally comes out as `somepackage-1.2.5-1.ferd30.x86_64.rpm`, instead of `.fc30`, so I can differentiate.